# Docs for Xcode grant access issue

Tags: xcode

I have xcode 6 installed on Yosemite and I am trying to install docs for Xcode.  During the install it recommends that you grant access to the following directory so Xcode can use the docs.

```
~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/Docsets
```

It then opens a window for you to select the folder you want to grant access to.  However, the Library folder is hidden so there is no way to select the recommended folder.  Not sure what to do next.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To show hidden folders use the following command in terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool YES; killall -HUP Finder
```

This is from [this Ask Different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58714) which provides more details and a command to reverse it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  unfortunately it did not work.  The window that is opened during install appears to be a modified open dialog box with  the open button replaced with "Grant Access".

Comment: I forgot to mention that it does make the Library folder visible in Finder, but not during Docs for Xcode installation.

Comment: ~/Library is hidden and doesn't show in the `Please click Grant Access` dialog window.  Perform `chflags nohidden ~/Library` in a terminal window in order to be able to drill into it, without making a global change.  You will also need to create the full directory tree in the terminal window.